# Sublime Text Regex Syntax to Match Ending Bracket

Tags: regex, sublimetext2, sublimetext3, sublimetext

I have a huge SQL query that looks like this:

```
SELECT Attr1 AS [Attr1], Attr2 AS [Attr2], ... AttrN AS [AttrN] from Table
```

Using Sublime Text, I want to remove the `AS [Attr1], AS [Attr2]` etc. as they are redundant and transform the query in to this form:

```
SELECT Attr1, Attr2, ... AttrN from Table
```

So far I have tried `AS[\W\w]*\]` but selects everything after the first `AS` up to the last `]`. But I am supposed to stop at the next `]`, How can I do this in Sublime Text?

Comment: In your opinion, what's `[\W\w]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [non-greedy](http://www.ultraedit.com/support/tutorials_power_tips/ultraedit/non-greedy-perl-regex.html) matchers:

```
 AS \[.*?\]
```

Replace with nothing

Answer (score 1):

Use `AS[\W\w]*?\]`.  This is a *reluctant* match so it will only match up to the *first* `]` rather than the last.  I think it would be better to use:

```
 AS .*?]
```

since attribute values could possibly have `AS` in them.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `(\w+) AS \[\1\]` with `\1`.

Comment: Of course it did, I tested it on SublimeText version 2.0.2 with your input. It does it flawlessly.

Comment: Sorry about that. Turns out my whole word search was turned on, which resulted in only finding the first result. :) +1

Comment: @hyde I thought it would be something like that :)